# Can we check the translated function calls generated by Cypher or Gremlin?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

I believe internally Cypher / Gremlin translate statement into corresponding Java method calls. Is there a way to trace what method calls in run?

For example, in Hibernate, we can specify "show sql" to see generated sql statement.

[Edit]
The reasonws I want to do that:
1. For Debugging purpose:
To find out why the cypher / gremlin doesn't produce the expected result.

1. For learning purpose:
   To find what's happening under the hood
2. For optimization:
   To find out where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

In Cypher, that is planned for the coming months to add. Ultimately, yes, currently the methods used under the Hood are the Java Neo4j core API and the Traversal Framework. Mind adding a case that is causing you problem?

Comment: Added usecases. Basically debugging is the main reason.

Answer (score 0):

For Gremlin, do a .toString() at the end of your Gremlin expression to see which Pipes (http://pipes.tinkerpop.com) it ultimately compiles down to.

Comment: gremlin> g.V.toString()
==> null